# Run each express request in new fork

Tags: javascript, node.js, fork, node-cluster

So I'm trying to implement forking all express requests to setup different `uid` per fork.

My current approach I just setup `euid` and restore it after a request like this:

```
  const mainUID = process.geteuid();
  app.get('/', () => {
        process.seteuid(500);
        // some action1 that requires privelegies of user id 500
        // some action2 that requires privelegies of user id 500
        process.seteuid(mainUID);
  });
```

But in case of concurrent requests it fails because after `action1` and `action2` some source code could be executed.

So I read some information about cluster module: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html but I have no idea how to use it in my case.

The more preferred way for me to create fork for each express request without splitting actually javascript code... So is it possible?

Comment: Check [Workers](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html) instead `Cluster`. P.S. I don't understand what do you need exactly.

Comment: @AikonMogwai I need per-request fs module to have current request user permissions